# Need to re-install libraries before every build (Carthage)

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage

My team and I are working on a Swift project (Swift 5 - XCode 11), and decided to use Carthage as our dependency manager to handle libraries such as SwiftyJSON, SDWebImage and MapBox. We have done the setup as specified on Carthage's GitHub: created a Cartfile, downloaded the libraries, dragged the files onto the "Frameworks, Libraries & Embedded content" part of XCode, added a Build stage as Carthage requests it...

My problem is: after almost every successful build, when I try to run the application, the build fails because one of the packages is not recognised: the message says: "Swift compiler error. No such module 'SwiftyJSON'" (or any of the other libraries).

To sort out this problem temporarily, I re-download again all packages by running:

```
$ carthage update --platform ios
```

The problem is that I need to re-do this update every time I build my application, otherwise it fails. None of my other three teammates are facing this issue.

Would be really helpful if someone knew the source of this problem, I have tried almost everything!

Thank you!

Comment: Zip up one of your coworkers working project directories and copy that to your machine. Does building work with those files?

Comment: It worked the first time! (Had to update my XCode version to match my teammate's Swift version).
Then, I started working on my own branch and the same issue appeared again